# How can I get fixed IP address on my vagrant even when I move to other network?

Tags: networking, ip, vagrant, static-ip-address

I'm using `vagrant` as Linux machine.
I'm a student and I'm coding in like everywhere such as home, classroom, univ, cafe, library, etc. 
The problem is that everytime I move to other place, I have to `halt` the vagrant machine and re-`up` again because the network is changed.

For example, I do some coding in cafe, where the private network IP address is 192.168.1.x. Now, I move to other place, say classroom, where the IP address this time is 192.168.99.x.

Since, IP has been changed, I have to reboot the vagrant machine. Although it takes only couple of mins but it is kinda bothering much to me.

I want to keep programming on my vagrant environment even if network environment has been changed. Need your help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can have static IP wether you're using private or public network, just by specifying which IP you want to use

for public network:

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.17"
```

for private network:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

While the answer provided by Frédéric Henri is accurate, it may not actually be helpful. The problem with setting a static IP in the Vagrantfile is when you change networks (or subnets) as you described, the network device in charge of handing out IPs might not be willing to give that IP back to you - it may already be in use, or on another subnet or network.

Assuming you're trying to regain network connectivity from the Guest, you can just reboot the adapter or network interface you need in the Guest by doing the following (from the Guest):

```
ifdown eth0
ifup eth0
```

Where `eth0` is the name of the network adapter you need to restart. You can verify this by running `ifconfig` on your Guest and determining which network interface is being used to get the IP you want to renew.

See this [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43022/how-can-i-restart-a-network-interface) for more information.